# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ won't connect to WiFi

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I got new internet so I tried to connect my Pi to the new internet by modifying `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and now it looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU

network={
    ssid="<new wifi name>"
    psk="<new wifi password>"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

The WiFi network is WPA2 and the SSID and password are correct. On the taskbar if I click on the WiFi icon it even lists the nearby WiFi networks, including the one I'm trying to connect to. The one I'm trying to connect to is 5G. How do I get this working?

When using either the terminal or GUI the WiFi icon stays at the disconnected state. My phone is able to connect to both 2.4 and 5G fine, and I have double-checked the password.

Comment: Did you try connecting in the GUI

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work.

Comment: 1: are you sure you have a 3+, 2: look in the output of `dmesg` just after booting the pi ... look for any errors etc regarding wifi

Comment: Yes, I am sure. And from what I can see there are no errors regarding WiFi from `dmesg`.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not very helpful. What did happen when you tried? What are you trying to connect to? If you can't connect in the GUI editing files won't help.

Comment: When using either the terminal or GUI the WiFi icon stays at the disconnected state. My phone is able to connect to both 2.4 and 5G fine, and I have double-checked the password.

Comment: My router has two sets of username and password, one set for 2.4G, another for 5G.  If yours also has two sets, perhaps you can try the 2.4G pair for phone and then rpi.

Comment: So I set up my dual band WiFi router (NetGear AC1750) two WiFi networks, with two sets (one 2.4GHz, another 5GHz) of SSID and paraphases.  I used my Rpi3B+ GUI Desktop top right most menu top to connect to 2.4G, checked it OK.  Then I disconnected it, and connected to the 5G WiFi network and also found it OK.  My conclusion is that for Rpi3B+ stretch 9, NetGear 1750 dual band WiFi router, there is no connection problems.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the hotspot you try to connect to, provide connections on the 2,4 GHz and 5 GHz band with the same ssid. Maybe there is a confusion on the RasPi? You can try to force a connection only with 2,4 GHz or 5 GHz. To connect on 2,4 GHz add a line to `wpa_supplicant.conf` so it looks like this:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=AU

freq_list=2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472
network={
    ssid="<new wifi name>"
    psk="<new wifi password>"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

To connect only on 5 GHz use this line:

```
freq_list=5170 5180 5190 5200 5210 5220 5230 5240 5260 5280 5300 5320 5500 5520 5540 5560 5580 5600 5620 5640 5660 5680 5700
```

Answer (score -1):

change wifi country to US. it is strange but it works. some kind of bug. 5g on this model works with US but not with european codes

Comment: Another user has observed that *"It is illegal to use unsupported frequencies (at least in AU), and due to the different bands may not work"*.